# How to filter dropdown values of a column in sharepoint online based on the values on another column within same list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-2016

consider i have two columns eg: country & city(both are lookup columns) , what i need is that for eg: I choose Canada as value in country column , then the dropdown values in city column should only contain cities within Canada. likewise for other countries also..
Anyone please help !

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about cascading dropdown which is dependent dropdowns with look up fields.
All you need to do is
Step 1: create a country list
Step 2: create a city list
Step 3: add a new lookup column in city list named as country which is a look up to country list.
Step 4: final output list. In which you will add two lookup columns as Country and City.

Once done with list structure you can use power apps which is most recommended with SharePoint modren sites, SP service code with content editor webpart in classic view of list page or use infopath.

For power apps:
https://youtu.be/kzvMbmb5pmo

For sp service code in content editor:
https://youtu.be/OcTI_UQ55TM

For info path 2013:
https://youtu.be/xm4YQ3FEctw

Please mark answer if this helps you

Comment: can i filter the dropdown based on values of two columns in the list

Comment: Obviously Yes you can. Depends upon your logic and need.

Comment: Which approach you want to use? PowerApps, SP Service Code or Info Path?

Comment: powerapps i prefer

Comment: By Filter the dropdown based on two columns means, you want to search cities by two columns like region and country ?